# SQL Server : master records and display number of detail records for each

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have a `Master` and `Detail` table, the `Detail` linking to the `Master` row on a FK reference.

I need to display all the data from the `Master` table, and the corresponding number of details for each record, i.e.

`MASTER` table:

```
ID Name  Age
-------------
1  John  15
2  Jane  14 
3  Joe   15
```

`DETAIL` table:

```
MasterID Subjects
---------------------
1        Trigonometry
1        Chemistry
1        Physics
1        History
2        Trigonometry
2        Physics
```

Thus, when I ran this SQL statement, I would get the following result:

```
ID   Name   Age  #Subjects
-----------------------------
1    John   15   Trignometry
1    John   15   Chemistry
1    John   15   Physics
1    John   15   History
2    Jane   14   Trignometry
2    Jane   14   Physics
```

Is this possible? Any idea?

Comment: Hint:  `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: wouldn't it multiply the records

Comment: . . (1) That is what you want.  (2) What happened to Jane/Physics?

Comment: By the way, seems silly to store age in the database as it constantly changes, better store DOB and calculate it off that

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a `LEFT JOIN` is what you are looking for

**Example**

```
 Select A.*
       ,B.Subjects
  From  Master A
  Left Join Detail B on A.ID=B.MasterID
```

**Results**

```
ID  Name    Age Subjects
1   John    15  Trigonometry
1   John    15  Chemistry
1   John    15  Physics
1   John    15  History
2   Jane    14  Trigonometry
2   Jane    14  Physics
3   Joe     15  NULL      -- <<<< Notice the NULL
```